# calculate X from the equation below?

Tags: logarithms

2^(log(2x,x+2))+3^(log(2,x+3))=sqrt(-1-x)

Can someone help me with this equation
I don't know how to start
Any hint would be appreciated
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean $$2^{\log_{2x}(x+2)}+3^{\log_{2}(x+3)}=\sqrt{-1-x}$$
then the domain gives $x>0$ and $x\leq-1$, which is impossible.

Comment: so we can say that 2x must be greater than 0 right? 2x>0? cause i had doubts about that? Does that mean that in any logarithmic equation we must write base as greater than zero ?

Comment: @John Doe Yes, you are right. If we write $\log_{a}b$ then $a>0$, $b>0$ and $a\neq1$ by definition.

Comment: okay thank you very much :)